# data.table::setorder changes underlying variables

Tags: r, sorting, dataframe, data.table

I noticed that `setorder` seems to change variables it should not touch at all. A simple code example explains this best:

```
library(data.table)
x <- 1:3
y <- 3:1
data <- data.frame(x.dat=x, y.dat=y)
setorder(data, y.dat)
x
```

The variable x has been reordered and now also reads 3 2 1 . This looks like a bug in the `setorder` command to me. 
If one inserts some additional command modifying x between the data frame Definition and the `setorder`, the effect disappears.

**Edit:** I just rerun the code and the effect disappeared. It seems like this issue was fixed some time between now and my first post a year ago. Specifically 1.10. versions of data.table have the effect, in 1.11.8 it works as it should.

Comment: Yes I agree it's a weird behavior, `x` should not be reordered by running `setorder` on `data`.

Comment: Related issue: [Mixing use of data.frame and data.table in R 3.1+](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/710)

Comment: The order of `x` does not change if you use `setorder` on a `data.table`: `data <- data.table(x.dat = x, y.dat = y)`; `setorder(data, y.dat)`; `x`

Comment: If we insert a line`if (!is.data.table(x)) x = copy(x)` into the start of `setorder` this problem goes away, supporting the suggestion that this behaviour could be related to whether setorder operates on x by reference or on a copy of x.

Comment: can't reproduce.

Comment: @quarague please post an answer update the issue being fixed, so the question can be considered as answered. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just rerun the code and the effect disappeared. It seems like this issue was fixed some time between now and my first post a year ago. Specifically 1.10. versions of data.table have the effect, in 1.11.8 it works as it should.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `datatable.setorder`, like all the `set*` functions, sorts the table *by reference*, and a `data.frame` is just a collection of references to columns. See the [R documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/data.table/versions/1.12.0/topics/setorder). Sorting a table of course means sorting all the columns of the table, so the columns get sorted.